# Decode HTML Entity in Kendo Editor without losing styles and colors

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, decode, encode, kendo-editor

I have a problem: 
During postback if special characters were entered, I see them in the editor with the encoding.

How do I decode them?

Eg `à` becomes `&agrave;`;

> I need to decode `&agrave;` to `à`

Example in [Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/uYUcOcEm)

If I try to do someting like that:

```
    var lDecodedValue = $("<div/>").html($("#editor").val()).text();
    editor.value(lDecodedValue);
```

It works, however I **lose any styles or colors** inserted in the text, I would like to preserve them.

Comment: Try to change the encoded attribute to true in $("#editor").kendoEditor({  encoded: true});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the encoded for the kendo editor to true:

```
$("#editor").kendoEditor({
  encoded: true
});
```